# open pdf file stored in db as binary data

Tags: c#, .net

if I have pdf file stored in sql server as binary data, varbinary(MAX) how can I retrieve it to open that file?

I have following

```
if(myObject.PdfFile != null)
{
   MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(myObject.PdfFile);
   // what to do with this ms to open file?
}
```

Comment: Write it to a temp file and run process with an Acrobat or with process and `ShellExecute`

Answer (score 2):

You can use the **HttpResponse BinaryWrite method**:

```
   var bytes = reader.GetSqlBytes(index);
    Response.BinaryWrite(bytes.Value);
```

Answer (score 2):

The below lines of code will be helpful for you. "myobject" is class file with proerties Attach_name,Attach_Type etc. Attach_Doc is property of type byte[].

```
Response.Clear();
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + myobject.ATTACH_NAME);
Response.ContentType = myObject.ATTACH_TYPE;// doc.DOCUMENT_TYPE;
Response.BinaryWrite((byte[])myObject.ATTACH_DOC);
Response.Flush();
Response.End();
```

Answer (score 0):

you will have to call a  stored procedure or inline query to select the varbinary column.

Then save the byte[] into a file with extension of .pdf

then you use process to open pdf with adobe reader

Answer (score 0):

if Not wanting to hijack other answers but to clarify... if your application is a web application/webpage then as user1081802 and SpiderCode said you could use

```
Response.BinaryWrite
```

If, however, if it is not a web application then you would need to save the binary data as a file to you hard disk and open it from there as liquidsnake786 suggested.